# How to display the user name that created the profile (the owner of the profile)?

Tags: templates, drupal, twig

I have a site with Drupal 8 and I want to customize the templates of my pages.

I use the module:

- "Profile" https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/profile

Here is my template to customize the profile page:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 *
 * Default theme implementation for profiles.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - content: Items for the content of the profile.
 *   Use 'content' to print them all, or print a subset such as
 *   'content.title'. Use the following code to exclude the
 *   printing of a given child element:
 *   @code
 *   {{ content|without('title') }}
 *   @endcode
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the wrapper.
 * - profile: The profile object.
 * - url: The profile URL, if available.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<div{{ attributes.addClass('profile--personnel--teaser') }}>

  <div class="views-row">

    <h3 class="views-teaser-title">
      {{ ??? USERNAME ??? }}
    </h3>

  </div>

</div>
```

How to display the user name that created the profile (the owner of the profile) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Owner Object from `profile`. Its an available variable in that page. You can use kint to view that variable

```
{{kint(profile.getOwner())}}
```

From that you can get the name, mail etc.. of owner

```
{{ profile.getOwner().name.value }}
{{ profile.getOwner().mail.value }}
```